# Diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Im given a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ so that:

$T(1,-1,0)=(a-4,a+6,0)$ and $T(1,1,0)=(-5,-5,0)$ and $T(1,1,1)=T(2,2,2)$.

I have found the Matrix Representation of T:

A=$\begin{bmatrix}λ+5 &0&0\\a+1&λ+5&0\\0&0&λ-2\end{bmatrix}$

And the Characteristic Polynomial:

$(λ-2)(λ+5)^2$

I need to find all the values of a for which this transformation is diagonalizable and the ones for which its not. Can some one please help me solve this problem?

Comment: What you call "a matrix representation" of $\;T\;$ seems rather to be the matrix of $\;\lambda I-B\;$ , with $\;\lambda\;$ some variable on the field and $\;B\;$ the **actual** matrix rep. of $\;T\;$ .

Comment: You should find the matrix $A$ depends on $a$ and not on $\lambda$.

Comment: how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

$$\;B:=\left\{\;v_1=(1,-1,0)\;,\;\;v_2=(1,1,0)\;,\;\;v_3=(1,1,1)\;\right\}$$

is a basis of $\;\Bbb R^3\;$, we can write the matrix rep. of $\;T\; $ wrt $\;B\;$ :

$$\begin{align*}&(a-4\,,\,a+6\,,\,0)=&-5v_1&+(a+1)v_2&+0\cdot v_3&\\&(-5,-5,0)=&0\cdot v_1&+(-5)\;\;\;v_2&+0\cdot v_3\\&(2,2,2)=&0\cdot v_1&+\;\;\;\;\;\;0\cdot v_2&+2\cdot v_3\end{align*}\;\;\;\implies$$

$$[T]_B=\begin{pmatrix}-5&0&0\\
a+1&-5&0\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$$

It's easy to see the characteristic polynomial of the above matrix is $\;(t+5)^2(t-2)\;$ , and thus it is diagonalizable iff the geometric multiplicity of $\;-5\;$ equals its algebraic multiplicity, which is $\;2\;$, so we calculate its eigenspace for $\;-5\;$ :

$$\begin{align*}(a+1)x&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=0\\&-7z=0\end{align*}$$

Now, since for sure $\;z=0\;$, we **must have** that $\;a+1=0\iff a=-1\;$ , otherwise *also* $\;x=0\;$ and the solution subspace has dimension $\;1\;$ instead of the wanted $\;2\;$.